# Is there a way to specify a Mongo database name for Meteor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, configuration, database

In my Node.js endpoints I open a connection to a Mongo database thus:

```
dbs.mongodb.open('myDb', function(){
    myApp.aggregate(query, function(){});
})
```

Now I'm trying to build an analytics dashboard in Meteor using the same database, but can't figure out how to point Mongo to 'myDb'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our workaround:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# correct port need to be specified
export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb"
meteor
```

Comment: this is what worked for me also. for clarity, i created a shell script at config/env.sh with the line:

 `export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb"`

Answer (score 2):

I created /server/main.js with the following contents:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
 process.env['MONGO_URL'] = "mongodb://localhost/myDb";
});
```

I'll report back if it worked

Comment: ... and then he never came back. Death by DB.

Comment: it probably did work, that meteor project got scrapped fast in favor of a react/node platform. where does the time go?